# Count shapes that may have holes in them

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to count the number of shapes in an image.
I have followed this [tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/10/20/finding-shapes-images-using-python-opencv/) and I am using getContours

```
contours, h = cv2.findContours(255 * oBW.copy().astype('uint8'), 
                                  cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

When my original image is:
[image: Original]

oBW is the inverted image:
[image: Inverted]

I want to find two shapes (the two squares):
[image: Two Squares]

But instead I am getting 4...
First:
[image: First]

Second:
[image: Second]

Third:
[image: Third]

And Fourth:
[image: Fourth]

How can I get only the two black shapes?
Thanks.

Comment: you have to create the shapes from the contours which is possible because you have access to the hierarchy level of each contour.

Comment: use matlab's `bwlabel`.